# Swift 5 - Layout errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uistackview

Why do I get errors like that shown in the image?  I have a horizontal stack embedded in a vertical stack, and want a left and right margin for the label and text field of 50 points from the leading and trailing edges of the vertical stack it sits inside
[Errors1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SucCI.png)
[Errors2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeIwr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir instead of giving it constraints add two cushion views of 50 points in horizontal stack with background color to be clear color ... you will get the same effect with stack view fill mode proportional fill ...